# Algorithm for creating random lists from an existing list in bash

Tags: bash, algorithm, random

I have a list of IDs like below:

```
xxx_date1
xxx_date2
xxx_date3
yyy_date1
yyy_date2
zzz_date1
xyy_date1
xyy_date1
...
...
```

`xxx_date1` and `xxx_date2` means that subject xxx had separate visits at `date1` and `date2`.
I need to write a script in bash to create random lists (of equal size) of only unique IDs. an example would be like below:

```
xxx_date1
yyy_date1
zzz_date1
xyy_date1
...
```

a second list could be:

```
xxx_date2
yyy_date1
zzz_date1
xyy_date1
...
```

How can I create all possible lists of unique IDs?
I appreciate any hint or idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `shuf` to do it like

```
shuf -n <list_size> src_list_file
```

to use your file with the source ideas and then get only some size list of random lines from the file.

That won't create all the lists, well, not without calling `shuf` a lot, but if what you want is a random list of entries this should get it done for you.

As rici pointed out, your original source looks like it has duplicates, and you perhaps do not want those in the output, so one way to address that would be:

```
sort -u <src_list_file> | shuf -n <list_size>
```

if the original list is not already sorted, or just

```
uniq <src_list_file> | shuf -n <list_size>
```

if they are alredy sorted

Comment: `shuf -n <list_size> list_file` would obviate the need for `head`. But you're missing a call to `uniq`, based on the rather imprecise problem description.

Comment: Hi Rici, can you elaborate more? I didn't get what you mean. Thank you

Comment: @rici thanks for the catch on `-n`, but shuf doesn't add duplicate entries unless they're in the original file, does it?

Comment: @eric: It doesn't add duplicate entries unless they're in the original file, no. But in this case, looking at the example, it seems like they are. " xyy_date1 xyy_date1", for example.

Comment: @user3708408 rici pointed out something I wasn't handling that might be in your question, see if my updated answer helps